# How to get date after N months with same day and same week of a given date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am looking for some logic to get the date after N months having same day(Ex:Wednesday)  and same week(ex: first or second...) of a given date.

ex: 12-06-2013(Wednesday & 3rd week of June) is the given date.
here I am adding 3 months to the given date.
the result should be is 14-Aug-2013(Wednesday & 3rd week of Aug).

please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Are you looking for C# or C code? They'll be *radically* different. Also, you need to define "third week" very carefully... do you mean "the third Wednesday of the month" in this case? Or something else? And what do you want to happen if you're looking at the 5th Sunday (or something similar) and the target month doesn't have 5 Sundays? Basically, your question needs a lot more clarity.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What about edge case where there is no such date?

Comment: 12-05-2013 is 3rd week of June? When does a week start, does it start with 0 or 1?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am looking for C# code only. I mean that is third Wednesday of the month and if it is 5th week of the month I am considering it as last week of the month.

Comment: @SonerGönül  my code is in

Comment: @TimSchmelter ya it is 3rd week of June according to my code.here June 1 & 2 will be first week and 3rd to 9th will be second after that 10 th to 16th will be 3rd week.

Comment: @user2477207: But `12-05-2013` is may not june.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not able to see your post which you posted some code to fix could you please share again. Thanks.

Comment: @user2477207: Sorry, i have seen a problem with different cultures and i have not yet the time to correct it. So i have deleted the approach.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I'd personally use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library to do this. It's entirely possible to do this with `DateTime`, but I'd personally find it harder. I'd also encourage you to use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) in general, of course, as a better date/time API. So I'd have something like:

```
static LocalDate AddMonthsPreserveWeekDayAndWeek(LocalDate start, int months)
{
    // This isn't the week of month in the "normal" sense; it's the nth
    // occurrence of this weekday.
    int week = ((start.DayOfMonth - 1) / 7) + 1;

    // This will usually give the same day of month, but truncating where
    // necessary
    LocalDate monthsAdded = start.AddMonths(months);
    LocalDate endOfPreviousMonth = monthsAdded.AddDays(-monthsAdded.Day);

    // Get to the first occurrence of the right day-of-week
    LocalDate firstRightDay = endOfPreviousMonth.Next(start.IsoDayOfWeek);

    // Usually this will be right - but it might overflow to the next month,
    // in which case we can just rewind by a week.
    LocalDate candidate = firstRightDay.PlusWeeks(week - 1);
    return candidate.Month == firstRightDay.Month ? candidate
                                                  : candidate.PlusWeeks(-1);
}
```

This is completely untested though - you should *absolutely* have a bunch of unit tests (ideally which you write before even including this code) which test all kinds of edge cases you're interested in.

Comment: thanks @Jon Skeet I will test this. I think it will helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard MDSN year = 2013 month = 06 date = 12

1) **Get day of the week from the specific date (Sunday is 0)**

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(year, month, date);  
Console.WriteLine((int) dateValue.DayOfWeek);      // Displays 3 implying it is Wed
```

2) **Get the week of the month from the specific date**

```
DayofWeek = 3 (from previous calculation)
Day = 12 
EndOfWeek = Day + (6 - DayOfWeek) = 12 + 4 = 16  
NoWeek = 0
while (EndOfWeek > 0)
{
   EndOfWeek  -= 7;
   NoWeek++;        
}
```

=> NoWeek = 3

3) **Get first date after N month**

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1)

newDate.AddMonths(N); // Let it be 2 => August 1, 2013
```

4) **Get the day of the week for the new date**

```
newDay = newDate.DayOfWeek  // Return 4 implying Thursday
```

5) **Get the last day after NoWeek**

```
newDate.AddDays(6-newDay) => newDate.AddDays (6-4) => August 3,2013
NoWeek--;
while (NoWeek > 1)
{
    newDate.AddDays(7);
    NoWeek--;
}
```

=> newDate will be Augus 10,2013

6) **Calculte required date**

```
newDate.AddDays(DayofWeek) =>newDate will be August 14,2013
```